# Determine if IP address is contained in network expressed with CIDR Notation? (In Apex)

Tags: apex

Does anyone know of an easy way to determine, for example, that an IP address `10.1.2.2` is contained within a network with CIDR notation of `10.1.0.0/16`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no "easy" (i.e. built-in) method, but the calculation should be pretty straight-forward. Here's assuming no "bad data":

```
public Static Boolean inRange(String range, String ip) {
    String[] rangeParts = range.split('/'),
        ip1parts = rangeParts[0].split('\\.'),
        ip2parts = ip.split('\\.');
    Long iplow = (Long.valueOf(ip1Parts[0])<<24) +
        (Long.valueOf(ip1Parts[1])<<16) +
        (Long.valueOf(ip1Parts[2])<< 8) +
        (Long.valueOf(ip1Parts[3])    ),
        iphigh = iplow + ((1 << Long.valueOf(rangeParts[1])) - 1),
        iptest = (Long.valueOf(ip2Parts[0])<<24) +
        (Long.valueOf(ip2Parts[1])<<16) +
        (Long.valueOf(ip2Parts[2])<< 8) +
        (Long.valueOf(ip2Parts[3])    );
    return iplow <= iptest && iphigh >= iptest;
}
```

This is about as long as it'd be in any other language with decent support for parsing numbers from strings.